# Python/Tkinter: Apply .attributes() method to Frame vs. Window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Does Tkinter or underlying Tk framework support the ability to apply the equivalent of the attributes() method to Frames vs. Windows?

Specifically: I have forms with a message area that I would like to fade away in jquery-like manner, eg. display a non-modal status message that fades away. I know I can fade a Tkinter window via window.attributes("-alpha", alpha), but I don't see an equivalent way to achieve this effect with a Frame. (I know I could place a top-level message window over my dialog, but coordinating the position and size of this window to match the layout of my dialog sounds complicated).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do what you want. Tkinter only supports transparency on top-level windows.